# If $T$ has at least one eigenvalue that it's absolute value is at least $1$, then the method does not converge

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

While solving a problem about the Jacobi method from my textbook, I came across with the following statement:

> Let $T$ be the iteration matrix of the Jacobi method for matrix $B$. If $T$ has at least one eigenvalue that it's absolute value is at least $1$, then the method does not converge.

I'm trying to figure out why this statement is true. I tried to prove it for myself but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm guessing it has something to do with the connection between the eigenvalues of $T$ and the singular values of $B$? Or maybe it has something to do with the spectral radius? Also, is it true for all iteration methods or only for Jacobi?

Comment: Was the question ultimately resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The original exercise is poorly stated. The correct statement is the following:

*If the iteration matrix has an eigenvalue with modulus at least one, then there exists a right-hand side vector for which Jacobi's method will fail to converge.*

Jacobi's method for the linear system $Ax=b$ is a special case of the stationary iteration $$x_{k+1} = G x_k + f, \quad x_0 = 0$$
where $G$ is the iteration matrix. By induction on $n$ we see that
$$x_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} G^j f.$$
If $\|G\|<1$ for any matrix norm induced by a vector norm, then the sum
$$x = \sum_{j=0}^\infty G^j f$$
is absolutely convergent and hence convergent. The sum is
$$ x = (I - G)^{-1} f.$$
Now if $G$ has an eigenvalue of modulus at least 1, then the sum will not necessarily converge for all $f$. In particular, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $G$ and $f$ is an eigenvector of $G$ corresponding to $\lambda$, i.e., $Gf = \lambda f$ and $f \not = 0$, then
$$ x_n = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \lambda^j f$$
If $|\lambda| \geq 1$, then the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ cannot converge, because the individual terms $\lambda^j f$ do not tend to zero. We have
$$ \|\lambda^j f\| = |\lambda|^j \|f\| \ge \|f\| \not = 0.$$
If $|\lambda|<1$, then the sequence will converge in exact arithmetic. However, rounding errors are likely to introduce a component in the direction of an eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue with modulus at least one. This will immediately lead to divergence. We conclude that the stationary iteration is not safe for practical computations if the iteration matrix has a eigenvalue of modulus at least one.